# Does defining variables within a loop matter?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, variables, definition

This is a piece of code I am writing.

```
var cList:XMLList = xml.defines.c;
var className:String;
var properties:XMLList;
var property:XML;
var i:int,l:int;
var c:XML;

for each(c in cList)
{
    className = String(c.@name);

    if(cDict[className])
    {
        throw new Error('class name has been defined' + className);
    }

    if(className)
    {
        cDict[className] = c;
    }

    properties = c.property;

    i = 0,
    l = properties.length();

    if(l)
    {
        propertyDict[className] = new Dictionary();

        for(;i<l;i++)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I defined all variables outside of loops. I am always worried, that if I defined them inside the loop, it might slow down the process speed, though I don't have proof - it's just a feeling.

I also don't like that the as3 grammar allows using a variable name before the defintion. So I always define vars at the very beginning of my functions.

Now I am worried these habits might backfire on me someday. Or is it just a matter of personal taste?

Comment: I took the liberty of trying to improve your English. Please comment if I got it wrong!

Comment: i don't mind,though it's very embarrassing :-)

Comment: Don't be embarrassed. A lot of people here are non-natives (neither am I), and helping each other out is what this platform is all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it doesn't matters because the compiler use variable **hoisting**, so it means that that the compiler **moves all variable declarations to the top** of the function :

More explanation on variables:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html

Answer (score 1):

AS3 IDEs allow you to use variable names before the declaration, because they know that the compiler uses a mechanism called "hoisting" to move *all* variable definitions to the top of a function, anyway. This happens without you noticing it, so that you can conveniently keep your code more readable. Therefore, it does not really make a difference if you manually move all the definitions to the top - unless you like your code to be structured in that way.

For the same reason, variable declaration within loops does not affect performance, unless you keep those loops in separate functions - only then will it result in actual allocation of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of AS3 programmers, me including, would consider the way you have it now to be "the right" way, while putting variables inside any block to be the "wrong way". The speed does not matter in this situation, I'll try to present both side's arguments in as little biased way as I can.

1. Put variables definition as close to the code it is used in. The motivation is simple: if the variable is used somewhere, you might want to know where was it declared. This is useful if you aren't sure of type of the variable, or its modifiers. Normally, the declaration is also the place to put commentary.
2. Put variables at the place where they are *actually* declared. Even a seasoned ActionScript programmer may eventually confuse him- or herself by declaring variables inside blocks, where a seemingly uninitialized variable would suddenly contain some random value. The common case looks like this:

```js
for (var i:int; i < x; i++) {
    // this loop is entered exactly once, instead of `i' times
    for (var j:int; j < y: j++) { ... } 
}
```

There is also a long tradition, originating in the C89 standard (aka ANSI C), which didn't have block-scoped variables and would not allow variable definition inside a loop. This has been later altered so that variables were scoped to the block of code where they are declared. Many modern C-like languages, for example C# treat variables like that. So, in the example above, C# would re-initialize `j` every time the inner loop was entered.

Programmers with longer tradition of writing code in other C-like languages would be led to believe thus, once they see variables declared inside a block, that the variable is scoped to the block. The "hoisting" is thus thought of as counter-intuitive. Therefore error-prone.